# Share a single gif in swift

Tags: ios, swift, share, gif

I would like to create an app that is able to share a gif. The problem is that when I use this code, the app crashes and doesn't share anything. I tried to look on stack overflow for answers, but I found nothing.
I write below the code. What is wrong in this code?
Thanks a lot!

```
@IBAction func shareAction(sender: AnyObject) {
    let imageURL: NSURL = NSURL(string: "http://media.fyre.co/OM2K20rSJuMGATAFFXRK_6.gif")!
    let imageData: NSData = NSData(contentsOfURL: imageURL)!
    let objectsToShare: [AnyObject] = [imageData]
    let activityVC: UIActivityViewController = UIActivityViewController(activityItems: objectsToShare, applicationActivities: nil)
    self.presentViewController(activityVC, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First, you absolutely must not use `NSURL(string:)` in this way: you are trying to download a file from the network on the main thread. Thus you are synchronously blocking the main thread. That is forbidden. Download properly (using NSURLSession).

Second, your code contains two explanation marks (`!`). That means "Please crash me!" You can hardly complain if that's exactly what happens. If you don't want to crash, unwrap your Optionals properly.

Basically everything in your code is being done the lazy way. Do things properly instead.

Comment: You also cannot use `http:` in this way in iOS unless you've made arrangements in the _Info.plist_ file. iOS requires `https:` by default.

Comment: Ok thank you. I correctly follow the second part. The app no more crashes. The problem is that i can't use NSURLSession: let imageURL: NSURLSession = NSURLSession(configuration: "media.fyre.co/OM2K20rSJuMGATAFFXRK_6.gif")

Comment: That's now how you use NSURLSession. Learn to use it.